# Access Reports and C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have predefined reports already made in an Access database,
Is there a way to call the Access reports already defined in Access from a c# desktop application?

Comment: Did you try searching for "access reports c#"? The first result contains [Print or Preview an Access Report in c#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-access-using-visual-c#print-or-preview-an-access-report)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask], then improve question (edit)!